# Error al rellenar un drodpwn con una lista de objeto en asp.net

Tags: asp.net, aspx

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error al rellenar un drodown con una lista de objetos:

System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'WebApplication1.Customer' no contiene una propiedad con el nombre 'Name'.'

El codigo del archivo .aspx es:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID = "ddlCustomers" runat="server">
       </asp:DropDownList>
```

El codigo del .aspx.cs es:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.Name = "customer1";
        customer.CustomerId = 1;

        Customer customer2 = new Customer();
        customer2.Name = "customer2";
        customer2.CustomerId = 2;

        List<Customer> cutomerList = new List<Customer>();
        cutomerList.Add(customer);
        cutomerList.Add(customer2);

        ddlCustomers.DataSource = cutomerList;
        ddlCustomers.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlCustomers.DataValueField = "CustomerId";
        ddlCustomers.DataBind();     
    }       
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId;
    public string Name;
}
```

¿Alguien podria corregir mi codigo para que el dropdown cargue correctamente la lista de objetos?.

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes que ponerle los metodos `get()` y `set()` de esta manera, `public string propertyName {get; set;}` a las propiedades. Ya que una clase tiene propiedades que cogen valores `get()` y modifican o setean valores `set()`. Espero que esto haya servido de ayuda.